# Custom Post Types, Custom Taxonomies and Permalinks ?

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, permalinks

So let's say i register a custom taxonomy called:

```
Clients
```

With a few terms such as: `Microsoft, IBM, Apple`

Under a CPT (custom post type) called `projects`:

## Permalinks

`/%year%/%monthnum%/%taxonomy%/%postname%/` this is the structure i am using;

http://www.example.com/projects/ - Displays All posts under 'projects'

http://www.example.com/projects/clients/ Displays a 404

http://www.example.com/projects/clients/ibm/ displays all posts under `projects` with the term `ibm`

How can i get Wordpress to display an Index of all the posts under Clients? so for example if the user visited /projects/clients/ all the posts with Microsoft, Apple and IBM would be displayed.

I know a method is to use a page and then query into the page, but in essence of SEO, and relevance, i can not name the page-slug something else.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to write a custom rule. I did similar stuff for a recent project. Create a template, and assign it to a page, with slug as 'clients' (or anything you like, but change the slug in the following rule as well). Try the following code, use **functions.php**:

```
add_action('init', 'custom_rule');
function custom_rule()
{
    global $wp, $wp_rewrite;
    $wp_rewrite->add_rule('^projects/clients/', 'index.php?pagename=clients', 'top');
}
```

Then on that template, form a custom query with your desired params (clients taxonomy) and loop through it.

> Note: After you put the above code in your functions.php file, go to
>   Settings > Permalinks, and click on save.

Hope this helps (I recommend you try it locally first)!

Comment: where are you including that code Rutwick ?

Comment: Please check my edited answer...

Answer (score 0):

You cannot access the `clients` location because its not a term, its your taxonomy base.

`http://www.example.com/projects/clients/` is taxonomy base. Its like accessing `http://www.example.com/tags/` which doesn't work.

`http://www.example.com/projects/clients/ibm/` is taxonomy term URL. Its like accessing `http://www.example.com/tags/example` which works.

If you want to access `/clients/` URL then you should create a page with custom template that can display the contents of all posts under `/clients/` taxonomy.